# golang Converting math.MinInt64 string to int fails

Tags: go

given the following function:

```
func convertValue(contents string) (int, error) {
    return strconv.Atoi(contents)
}
```

when I run the following test

```
var convertValues = []struct {
    contents string
    value int
}{
    {"9223372036854775807", math.MaxInt64},
    {"−9223372036854775808", math.MinInt64},
}

func TestConvertValue(t *testing.T) {
    for _, values := range convertValues {
        value, err := convertValue(values.contents)
        if err != nil {
            t.Error("Expecting", values.value, "but got error", err.Error())
        }

        if value != values.value {
            t.Error("Expecting ", values.value, ", but got ", value)
        }
    }
}
```

it works for MaxInt64, but not for MinInt64.  I'm running this on a MacBookPro, so it's running in 64bit.  I have double checked this with the following

```
func TestIntSize(t *testing.T) {
    const PtrSize = 32 << uintptr(^uintptr(0)>>63)
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOOS, runtime.GOARCH)
    fmt.Println(strconv.IntSize, PtrSize)
}
```

and it returned

```
darwin amd64
64 64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/FtytYJkHSc

Switching to strconv.ParseInt and explicitly using int64 as the type seemed to help. I also had an issue with the dash character in your MinInt64 string, that might just be on my end, but worth checking and making sure it is the basic ASCII character not some kind of Unicode dash.

Comment: Was the dash char.  I thought I had typed it, but it appears not.

Comment: Glad that was it! It appears I had to use explicit int64 because I was using golang playground which uses 32bit pointers and ints